# A question on convergence of real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\frac{x_n}{n}$ tends to $0$ but $\frac{x_n}{n^\alpha}$ does not tend to $0$ for any $0 < \alpha < 1$ ?

More importantly is there a sequence of natural numbers with the above property?

Comment: That is true for that fixed $a$, but for $1> b >a >0$, again $\frac{x_n}{n^b}$ tends to $0$, so that can not be the answer

Comment: What about $x_n=n^{\alpha}$?

Comment: @Pspl $\alpha$ is not fixed

Answer (score 4):

Yes, take $$x_n=\frac{n}{\ln n}$$ for $n\geq 2$.

---

Edit: A very cool sequence of natural numbers which satisfies your condition is $$x_n=\pi(n),$$ where $\pi$ denotes the [Prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Less spectacular would be for example $$x_n=\left\lceil \frac{n}{\ln n}\right\rceil,$$ where the half-brackets denote „the smallest integer larger than...“

Comment: Thank you Maximilian. Getting old, I think. Should have occurred in my mind, though this is not actually the problem, but let me see if the answer can be used !!

Comment: @PDas Did it work for the original problem? 

Comment: @Maxmilian unfortunately no !! The better question should be can I choose a sequence of natural numbers $\{x_n\}$ with the above property ?

Comment: @PDas See what I have added